# How to detect collect formatted numbers and non-formatted numbers from a string using Regex

Tags: python, regex, formatting, numbers

I am developing a project in Python that normalizes any given strings to pure plain-text. The problem is that my input is quite irregular and some numbers are formatted (values, prices) and others are not formatted (years, age). I am trying to collect all of them, without really caring if it is formatted or not with the following script.

```
def get_nums(line):
   formatted_nums = re.compile('\d{1,3}[,.]\d{1,3}')
   nums = re.compile('\d+')
   formatted_nums_data = rm_repetitions(formatted_nums.findall(line))
   nums_data = rm_repetitions(nums.findall(line))
   return formatted_nums_data + nums_data
```

However, given the sentence:
*Rolls-Royce Motor Cars Inc. said it expects its U.S. sales to remain steady at about 1,200 cars in 1990.* It outputs me the following results:

```
[u'1,200', u'1', u'200', u'1990']
```

Nonetheless, the output that I want is:

```
[u'1,200', u'1990']
```

Is there any solution for this kind of problem? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Using `\d+` will find 1 and 200. If you only want 1900, then use `\d{4}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want one or more occurrences that is what `+` gives you

You want 4 occurrences so `{4}`

```
import re

def get_nums(line):
   formatted_nums = re.compile('\d{1,3}[,.]\d{1,3}')
   nums = re.compile('\d{4}') # CHANGE
   # using SET to remove duplicates
   formatted_nums_data = list(set(formatted_nums.findall(line)))
   nums_data = list(set(nums.findall(line)))
   return formatted_nums_data + nums_data

line = "Rolls-Royce Motor Cars Inc. said it expects its U.S. sales to remain steady at about 1,200 cars in 1990"   
print(get_nums (line))
```

```
['1,200', '1990']
```

Comment: One question, in other sentences I have number such as 200 and and 1,200, and I would like to get both. How should I proceed?

Comment: ('\d{3,4}'), min 3 max 4 digits!

Comment: The problem is that if a proceed like that in the example posted, I would get [1.200 , 200 , 1900]. The problem is more complex than it seems xD